# Sharing the same message contract for two actions

Tags: c#, wcf, soap

My services are supposed to parse a SOAP request for an action ILogging/LogMessage which has 'log-entry' as the root element inside the SOAP body. For that, I have a method LogMessage that expects parameter of type LogMessageRequest.

LogMessageRequest has the MessageContract attribute set with WrapperName as log-entry:

```
[MessageContract(WrapperName = "log-entry")]
public class LogMessageRequest
{
    ...
}
```

I am also expecting another SOAP request for an action ILogging/LogException with 'log-entry' as root element in the SOAP body. For this, there's a method LogException and a param of type LogExceptionRequest.

The difference between both the SOAP actions is that a child element 'message' inside 'log-entry' is different (for LogMessage, 'message' is a string and for exception, it's a complex entity).

The issue:
Since both LogMessageRequest and LogExceptionRequest have the same wrapper names (log-entry), I'm getting an exception originating from LogException saying "log-entry has already been exported by LogMessage".

I tried using the same request class for both and have the 'message' of type object. But that refuses to work.

Any pointers? (there's no scope of changing the SOAP request by the way).

Answer (score 0):

While there might be a way to match the different schemas with a common interface, I suggest a more prudent approach: build an adapter over one of the service interfaces to match the interface of the other.

This way, the ugliness is isolated and the application will only have to work with only one service interface.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can implement this using MessageContract/data contract from your description. You might be able to do it with XmlSerializer attributes, but it sounds like you will need to use the Message class in the operation contract and peek at the message xml to figure out which one it is.  Can you post the relevant bits of the  WSDL/SOAP definitions?